# how to avoid select queries (for every entity separately) before bulk update (Hibernate -spring data jpa)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, bulkupdate

Im using the saveAll method by spring-data-jpa.

I know that when i  update an entity, hibernate needs to re-attach the detached entity and thats why before the update it executes select statements.

But when i try to update about 10.000 entity it means also 10.000 select will be executed which is a performance issue.

Isnt there any way re-attach that detached entites as bulk?

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate does not trigger a select query for update method. It is the merge that triggers an extra select to avoid duplicate record error(NonUniqueObjectException). So, you can use update to persist the detached entity.

This [blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-merge-hibernate-save-update-saveorupdate/) by @vlad-mihalcea explains the behavior of different methods

Comment: spring-data checks the entity is new or not, if the entity will be updated (has ID),  the merge method is called and that would trigger select query.